# Check if a number is a power of another

Tags: python, recursion

I need to check whether a number is a power of another number.
given x, y, I need to check if there's an n such that x^n = y and if there is return True
I can't use math, %
for example -
b = 2, x=16 - True because 2^4 = 16
I need to solve this using recursion and I can't reach to any solution...

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = 2, 16
pow_of = 1
while pow(x, pow_of) <= y:
   if pow(x, pow_of) == y:
      print("True")
   pow_of += 1
```